# Link_Shared event for slack app not triggered

Tags: botframework, slack, slack-api

I am building a slack app and I also have a bot for this which is developed using Microsoft Botframework. I want to support link unfurling in my slack app so I have added all the events, permission scopes and domains for which to support link unfurling. But when I am sharing a message having a link of registered domain I am just getting a simple message event not the link_shared event. So please help in this why this is happening, Is it issue on the slack side or the Microsoft bot framework side and how to fix this issue.

**Updated:** Looks like the issue is with Microsoft bot framework as when I enter my api end point directly in the events api endpoint where slack sends the event then it is working fine but when I enter https://slack.botframework.com/api/Events/(bothandle) in the events api endpoint as mentioned by Microsoft bot framework to work with slack then I am not getting the event. So the issue is because of Microsoft botframework.

Comment: Could you please share your code? Have you test your code with other channels or on emulator?

Comment: @Grace What I have done is Registered the domains,added links:read and links:write permissions,added link_shared event in the slack app settings. Then I am using this code `registerBotMiddleware() {
    this.mBot.use(builder.Middleware.sendTyping());

    this.mBot.use({
      receive: (event, next) => {
      },
    });
  }` Here when I receive any event after user posted a message containing link of registered event I just receive event type as message not link_share. I have tested this in few public channels and on OS X platform Slack App.

Comment: @Grace What I figured out is this middleware will handle all the bot events in slack and link_shared event is a workspace event according to slack so I think this middleware will not be able to handle the workspace event. Can you please help me if above assumption is correct then how can I handle the workspace events of slack using botframework as slack is sending all the events to https://slack.botframework.com/api/Events/{YourBotHandle} which is the domain of botframework.

Comment: are you trying to render user's message to slack's link unfurling format? I think it's not possible for bot. But we can try to response to user and show the link by [Create a full-fidelity Slack message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata#create-a-full-fidelity-slack-message).

Comment: @Grace What I need is If a user is posting a message in general and that message contains a link then I want to capture the event that link is shared in the channel and then I want to attach some useful information and some preview using Slack unfurling functionality. So how do I get the event LINK_SHARED that is specified here [link](https://api.slack.com/events/link_shared).